# Can not get values in f.select for enum (gem mongoid-enum used)

Tags: mongodb, enums, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I have enum:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Enum
  enum :status, [:draft, :published], default: :draft
```

Now I want to get all enum values in select:

```
<%= f.select :status, Article.statuses %>
```

But have an error message:

```
undefined method `statuses' for Article:Class
```

There is really no method "statuses" for Article. Is it mongoid-enum bug or I do something wrong?

I use Mongoid 6 and 'mongoid-enum', github: 'monster-media/mongoid-enum' (optimized for mongoid 6)

PS. As temporary fix I use:

```
<%= f.select :status, {Draft: :draft, Published: :published} %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

> Article::STATUS

instead of

> Article.statuses